# Angular material: No provider for dialogRef

Tags: angular, angular-material

hey I'm trying to use angular material dialog and I face an issue:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatDialogClose -> MatDialogRef]: 
>         StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatDialogClose -> MatDialogRef]: 
>           NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!

module.ts:

```
...
import {
  MatDialogModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatExpansionModule
} from "@angular/material";

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    PostListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [PostCreateComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

component1:

```
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material";
 constructor(public dataService: DataService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}

    onEdit(postId: string) {
        this.dataService.editMode = true;
        this.dataService.postIdForEdit = postId;
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PostCreateComponent, {
          width: "500px"
        });
      }
```

component2:

```
 import { MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";


      constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        public dataService: DataService,
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PostCreateComponent>
      ) {}

      ...


      onAddPost(form, formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
   ...
           this.close();
        }

       close() {
 this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
```

I imported everything needed so why I get this error? where else I need to add the `MatDialogRef` instance? I have searched all over the net but found no answer to this problem .... thanks by heart

Comment: Add the MatDialogRef in providers array.

Comment: Where do you use MatDialogClose?

Comment: It could be something wrong with your template. Could you attach your HTML template for your dialog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular material No provider for MatDialog! Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735373/angular-material-no-provider-for-matdialog-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import **`MatDialogModule, MatDialog and MatDialogRef from @angular/material/dialog`** instead of **`@angular/material`**

**`import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';`**

Also you need to make sure that  **`MatDialogRef`** exists in providers array

```
providers: [{
  provide: MatDialogRef,
  useValue: {
    close: (dialogResult: any) => { }
  }
}]
```

[Github issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8419)

Comment: it needs to be there in the providers as well https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8419

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problem with the version between Angular Core, Material and CDK. I solved it by deleting `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` / and `yarn-lock` (if exist) and running a fresh npm install.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to the error & question here: [angular material No provider for MatDialog! Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735373/angular-material-no-provider-for-matdialog-error/61413350#61413350)

See my suggestion on that topic. My suggestion is to simplify the way your dialog gets instantiated. There's a way to use MatDialog such that the "parent" component is the only thing that needs to be aware of managing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

for component you need to import module in your module file in which you have registered your component as

**import { DialogsModule } from "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog";**

for component as

**import { DialogRef } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';**

and for testing file(spec) as

**import { DialogsModule, DialogRef } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';**

providers: [{
provide: DialogRef,
useValue: {
close: (dialogResult: any) => { }
}
}]